# Center a div with respect to viewport, on click while animating the position change

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to center a div, with respect to the viewport on click while animating the change in position.

I tried using CSS, adding the class on Click:

```
card{
width:500px;
height:500px;
transition: all 4s ease-in;
}

.active-card{
top:50%;
left:50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

but this causes the card to first get offset by -50% and then be brought back
so I figured I would have to calculate the offset using js and translate the card by that

```
const handleClick = () => {
let box = noteRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
let centerX = window.innerWidth / 2 - (box.left + box.right) / 2;
let centerY = window.innerHeight / 2 - (box.top + box.bottom) / 2;
console.log(centerX, centerY)
card.current.style.transform = `translate(${centerX}px ,${centerY}px)`;
}
```

I'm trying to find the x and y cord of the card and find how much I have to offset to get it to the center

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a few lines of JS/jQuery

The following example captures the current positioning, forces elements to absolute positioning, and animates the move to vertical & horizontal center.

Note: It's not a perfect solution for all use cases; check out how "NotClickable" shifts positions.  In other words, doing a css trick that transitions elements from "relative" to "absolute" or "fixed" has consequences.  And for nested elements the jQuery position() method will reveal limitations you'll have to deal with.

All that said check it out...

HTML

```
  <div class="YouMoveMe">Clickable</div>
  <span>NotClickable </span><span class="YouMoveMe">Clickable too</span>
  <div class="YouMoveMe">Clickable 3</div>
```

JS/jQUERY

```
window.onload=()=>{
 $(".YouMoveMe")
  .on({
   click:e=>{
    H=e.currentTarget;
    H.startLeft=$(H).position().left;
    H.startTop=$(H).position().top;
    $(H)
     .css({position:"absolute", left:H.startLeft, top:H.startTop})
     .animate({left:(window.innerWidth/2) - (H.clientWidth/2), top:(window.innerHeight/2) - (H.clientHeight/2)});
   }
  });
}
```